# ConcurrentLinkedQueue won't remove

Tags: java

I'd like to know in which case a ConcurrentLinkedQueue can't remove an element from its Collections. The item exists, it is inside the collection but calling

```
SomeConcurrentLinkedQueue.remove(item)
```

won't remove this item from the collection. Is the collection locked or something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue.remove(item)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) returns `false`, this means that `item` didn't compare equal to any of the queue's entries. If that's not what you're expecting, check the `item`'s `equals()` method for errors.

Another possibility (pointed out by @Louis Wasserman) is that the queue contains *multiple* occurrences of `item`. [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue.remove(item)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) would only remove one of them.

Comment: Well, this is not returning `false`, for I use a test to see if the item is in the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` :
`if(list.contains(item)){
   Log.d("Removed","Removed");
   list.remove(item);
  }`
The main problem is that item still exists inside list !

Comment: @turbodoom Which item do you mean? A simple test will show that list.contains(item) returns false after the list.remove(item) occurs

Comment: It might be that you have _multiple_ occurrences of the item in your list.  `queue.remove(item)` removes only one occurrence.